# How to Parse Json with an url in Android Studio

Tags: android, json

i have this Json

```
{'information':  [{"id_module":"123456","adresse_mac":"0.0.0.1","mot_de_passe":"mdp123"}]}
```

and i would like to put the "adresse mac" into a string using the url but i really don't know how to do this so if someone can help me it would be awesome.I did lot of research but the tutorials i found are bad.I'am a beginner it's my first app so just be tolerant

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .penaltyDialog()
            .build());

    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll()
            .penaltyLog()
            .build());





    JSONObject json = null;
    String str = "";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("the url i want");
}
    public void parseJson(String jsonString)
    {
        try
        {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONArray userdetails = json.getJSONArray("information");
            for (int i=0; i<userdetails.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject user = userdetails.getJSONObject(i);
                String address = user.getString("id_module");
                String name = user.getString("mot_de_passe");
                String userid = user.getString("adresse_mac");


                TextView url = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
                url.setText(userid);



            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}

    }
```

Comment: Can you put your whole code?

Comment: Just updated right now

Comment: What is not working in the above code?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting this JSON data from the url, I suggest you must use JSONParser class for parsing JSON. There are many methods to parse a JSON string. I personally use JSONParser. Google JSONParser.java and get it downloaded and copy into your source folder. Import JSONparser class into your activity, mostly if I am getting data from a URL using the internet I use Asynctask for parsing from url.

Here is AsyncTask

for calling AsyncTask use new Class_Name().execute();

```
class Class_Name extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // testing on Emulator:
    private String _URL = "Your_URL";


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
                    try {
            // Building Parameters if parameter present

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Pram1", param1));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            // Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("get data", json.toString());

            int id_module = json.getInt("id_module");
            String adresse_mac = json.getString("adresse_mac");
            String mot_de_passe = json.getString("mot_de_passe");




        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        }


}
```

## Codelord

Comment: There is no way to do this without GSON ?

Comment: You can customize it as you want to. By seeing your code I think you must use AsyncTask for not to crash your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("");
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("information");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject youValue = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String idModule = youValue.getString("id_module");
            // Use the same for remaining values
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope that helps